# memory consumption for a true color frame buffer

Tags: memory

What is the memory consumption for a true color frame buffer (with double buffering) on an XGA display? ("XGA" = 1024 x 768 pixels) How can I calculate this?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried, and explain what you currently understand?

Answer (score 4):

True color is 8 bits per color channel, so 3 bytes per pixel.  1024x768 is 785,408 pixels.  At 3 bytes per pixel that is 2,356,224 bytes.  Since it's double buffered we double that number to 4,712,448 bytes which is about 4.5MB.

Comment: I'm not sure there are that many true 24bit displays. I suspect many will probably pad each pixel out to 4 bytes, thus becoming 3145728, i.e. 3MB.

Comment: XGA is a specific standard from a while back, when they didn't have the memory to pad to 32bit. Check it out here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#XGA_.281024x768.29